# How is the matrix $(sI - A)$ called whose determinant is the characteristic polynomial of a (real valued) matrix $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, terminology, characteristic-polynomial

**Context:**

When calculating eigenvalues of a real valued matrix $A$ one often constructs an auxiliary polynomial matrix $M(s):= (sI - A)$ and then calculates its determinant $d(s):=\det\Big(M(s)\Big)$ – which is usually called the *characteristic polynomial* of $A$. The eigenvalues of $A$ are then the roots of that polynomial.

**Question:**

What is an established (or at least meaningful and self-explanatory) name for the polynomial matrix $M(s)$ (implicitly depending on $A$)?

Comment: I don't think there is any specific name for that matrix.

Comment: There is a [companion matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3721138/what-is-the-origin-of-the-companion-matrix) for each characteristic polynomial.

Comment: You could call it the inverse of the resolvent matrix of $A$

Comment: You can't call it the inverse of the resolvent if $(sI-A)^{-1}$ does not exist.